# extracting part of path using sub

Tags: r, regex

I'm attempting to extract a filename from a path in r. In a string like

```
someurl.com/vp/125514_45147_55144.jpg?_nc25244
```

I want to extract 125514_45147_55144

I'm using the following expression:

```
 sub(".*vp/(.*?)/.*", "\\1", input)
```

which works but it also strips the underscores:

```
1255144514755144
```

I cannot figure out how to retain the underscores

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you get? That doesn't seem to match what you posted. Here your `sub` is looking for a `/` after the number which doesn't match you r sample input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove dot and everything after it of the basename:

```
sub("\\..*", "", basename(x))
## [1] "125514_45147_55144"
```

If it is possible that there are dots in the filename then use this slightly more complex pattern:

```
sub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", basename(x))
## [1] "125514_45147_55144"
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest fixing it as

```
sub(".*/vp/([^/?]*?)\\.[^/?.]*(?:\\?.*)?$", "\\1", input)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeV1n8/2)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `/vp/` - a literal substring
- `([^/?]*?)` - Group 1 (its captured value is referenced by `\1` from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than `/` and `?`, as few as possible
- `\\.` - a dot
- `[^/?.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`, `?`  and `/`
- `(?:\\?.*)?` - an optional substring matching `?` and then any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

With `regmatches`/`regexec` the pattern becomes much clearer:

```
x <- "someurl.com/vp/125514_45147_55144.jpg?_nc25244"
regmatches(x,regexec("/vp/([^/?]*)\\.",x))[[1]][2]
## => [1] "125514_45147_55144"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/lkQPis)

Answer (score 2):

`stringr` alternative

```
library( stringr )
str_match( "someurl.com/vp/125514_45147_55144.jpg?_nc25244", "^.*/(.*?)\\..*$" )[[2]]
#[1] "125514_45147_55144"
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer of @G.Grothendieck, a regex-free solution using `dirname`, `basename` and `chartr`

```
x = 'someurl.com/vp/125514_45147_55144.jpg?_nc25244'
dirname(chartr(x = basename(x), ".", "/"))
# [1] "125514_45147_55144"
```

Assuming there is no dot in the filename.